# Bootstrap data-dismiss is not working for phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, dialog

I'm doing a shopping cart for my phonegap app, upon click on the cart button, a dialogue is supposed to pop out to prompt user they have succeeded in putting products into shopping cart. I'm using the model method of Bootstrap, I changed the coding exactly as the other one I saw others doing online, but I could only open the dialogue using href method instead of data-dismiss, and the close button of the dialogue is not working as well. So I deduce from the problems that there's something wrong with my data-dismiss.

Here's the trigger button which using the normal model way without href:
`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#SymAlertBox">
<img src="images/add-to-cart-btn.png" alt="Add To Cart">
</button>`

Shopping cart Dialogue as follows：

sym-app
js/sym-cart.min.js

```
        <div id="SymAlertBox" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="smallmodal" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 17px;">
            <div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 586px;"></div>
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" arua-hidden="true">&times;
        </button>
            <div class="modal-title text-center" id="SymAlertModalTitle">Add item to cart</div></div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="SymAlertModalBody">Item already in Cart</div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
        </div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Did you ever get it figured out?  I have the same problem...